# Passing value if statement to another if statement PHP

Tags: php, html, date

In my system have a calendar and at the top of the calendar have two button next and previous which is to get the next month year and previous month year.
The current month year now is November 2015. What I want is If I click next button then it will go to the next month  year December 2015 and if I click previous button then it will go back to the current month year which is November 2015. What happen now is, If i click next button then month year is December 2015, but if I click previous button the month year is October 2015 [decrements 1 from current month year(November 2015) but not decrements 1 from December 2015]

Any idea to solve this?

I only have idea which is to pass value from first statement `(isset($_POST['next)']))` to the second if statement `(isset($_POST['previous)']))`.

this is my php code:

```
/*increment decrement day month year with different format. check it*/
$CurrentMonthyyyymm = date('Y-m');
$month_year_Current =  date('F Y');  
$totday = date('t');

$totdayLastMonth= date('t', strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));      // eg: 31
$totdayNextMonth= date('t', strtotime("+1 month ", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));


$month_year_Last = date('F Y', strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));   // eg: December 2014
$month_year_Next = date('F Y', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));

$LastMonthyyyymm= date('Y-m', strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));    // eg: 2014-12
$NextMonthyyyymm= date('Y-m', strtotime("+1 month ", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));

/****** day month year next previous   *****/
if (isset($_POST['next']))
 {
  $_SESSION['i'] = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? ++$_SESSION['i'] : 1;
  $increment1 = $_SESSION['i'];

  $totday= date('t', strtotime("+$increment1 month ", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));
  $month_year_Next = date('F Y', strtotime("+$increment1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));
  $NextMonthyyyymm= date('Y-m', strtotime("+$increment1 month ", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));
}else{
  unset($_SESSION['i']);
}

// $NextMonthyyyymm; 
if (isset($_POST['previous'])) 
{
   $_SESSION['d'] = isset($_SESSION['d']) ? ++$_SESSION['d'] : 1;
   $decrement1 = $_SESSION['d'];

   $totday= date('t', strtotime("-$decrement1 month ", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));
   $month_year_Last = date('F Y', strtotime("-$decrement1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));
   $LastMonthyyyymm= date('Y-m', strtotime("-$decrement1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));
}else{
unset($_SESSION['d']);
}
```

Comment: this is your problem `$CurrentMonthyyyymm = date('Y-m');` you need to be setting this according to what was pressed. In other words it doesn't need to be the current month at all, but the selected month, or if none chosen then the current month

Comment: `$CurrentMonthyyyymm = isset($_POST['selectedDate']) ? date('Y-m', strtotime($_POST['selectedDate'])) : date('Y-m');`
you have to post your selected date.

Comment: ok, so if  I click next button, how can I pass the value $NextMonthyyyymm inside first if statement to the second if statement? because I need to use that value inside the second if statement to do the decrement

Comment: As mentioned, `$CurrentMonthyyyymm = date('Y-m');` should have a "default" (on load) setting which is what you have, then be able to change when the user clicks next or previous. The today date should equal whatever is currently selected.

Comment: Possibly all the default today dates should have that ability I think (just taking a quick look at your script)

Answer (score -2):

To solve the issue with the previous button decrementing the month incorrectly, you need to modify the logic in your code. Instead of incrementing and decrementing a session variable, you can directly calculate the previous and next month using the current month and year.

Here's an updated version of your PHP code:

```php
$CurrentMonthyyyymm = date('Y-m');
$month_year_Current = date('F Y');
$totday = date('t');

$totdayLastMonth = date('t', strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm))); // eg: 31
$totdayNextMonth = date('t', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));

$month_year_Last = date('F Y', strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm))); // eg: December 2014
$month_year_Next = date('F Y', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));

$LastMonthyyyymm = date('Y-m', strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm))); // eg: 2014-12
$NextMonthyyyymm = date('Y-m', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));

if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
  $NextMonthyyyymm = date('Y-m', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));
  $month_year_Next = date('F Y', strtotime($NextMonthyyyymm));
  $totday = date('t', strtotime($NextMonthyyyymm));
} elseif (isset($_POST['previous'])) {
  $LastMonthyyyymm = date('Y-m', strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));
  $month_year_Last = date('F Y', strtotime($LastMonthyyyymm));
  $totday = date('t', strtotime($LastMonthyyyymm));
}
```

In this updated code, when the next button is clicked, it calculates the next month and updates the necessary variables. Similarly, when the previous button is clicked, it calculates the previous month and updates the variables accordingly. This approach avoids the need for session variables and ensures that the month is incremented or decremented correctly based on the current month and year.

Make sure to replace the relevant parts of your existing code with this updated code.

Comment: Your four answers today appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.